# static From and To methods vs implicit and explicit Casting methods

Tags: c#, mvvm, casting, type-conversion, static-methods

I have read from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx) how to implement type conversion, and I know how to implement `ToType` and `FromType` methods. I need to know why many developers choose to build `FromType` and `ToType` methods when they can easily build conversions as specified?
Is there a performance benefit, or is it simply something developers choose for readability/comprehension?

I have a case where the ViewModel and Model are extremely related but I have to convert from one to another. When I look at a lot of libraries, it is evident that people don't cast or write conversion methods, instead go for static From and To methods, eg, in solazrizr. I am simply split, not knowing whether I can write `ViewModel vm = new Model();` (implicit cast), `ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)(new Model());` (explicit cast), or `ViewMode vm = ViewModel.FromModel(new Model());` (static from to method).

Is there any concrete reason why the From/To methods are preferred?

Comment: `ViewModel.FromModel` sounds like a factory method, not a conversion.

Comment: Have you ever tried to find code for implicit conversion in relatively big project? With "ToType" it is trivial since it is in your face - you know where it is used, you can easily "find all reference" and like... Try the same by looking at code that *may* have implicit conversion...

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I am sorry that I am unfamiliar with the naming convention, I'm a kiddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of reasons why I'd pick method:

- Rules for method matching are significantly easier to understand that implicit/explicit conversions. Even for basic numeric types such rules are sometimes not intuitive - like `1/2 < 1/10f`, conversions for two basically unrelated types will cause even more confusion.
- It is not possible to "auto-discover" conversions - while intellisence will suggest methods (including extensions) readily it is not the case for conversions
- Reading code with implicit conversions is harder as often reader will have no context what conversions are allowed.

For public APIs additional reasons for search optimization apply - it is much easier to search for method name than for something like "implicit conversion from ZZZ to YYY".

Comment: How about the exact case - from ViewModel to Model and vice versa?